Нужно сделать полностью асинхронного телеграмм бота
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
import asyncio
import sys

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text("Hi.")

async def run_bot(token: str) -> None:
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(token).build()
    
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    
    print("Бот запущен...")
    await app.run_polling()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    token = 'mytoken' 

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) 

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(run_bot(token)) 
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Бот остановлен.")
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")
    finally:
        loop.close()

Суть в том, что данный код работает когда уберу async run_bot, но почему нельзя что бы все было в async?
почему так нельзя делать или я что то не сделал?

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
import sys

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text("Hi.")

async def run_bot(token: str) -> None:
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(token).build()
    
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    
    print("Бот запущен...")
    await app.run_polling()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    token = 'mytoken'

    try:
        # Просто запускаем асинхронную функцию
        import asyncio
        asyncio.run(run_bot(token))  # run_bot будет вызван асинхронно
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Бот остановлен.")
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")

Использование asyncio.run() вместо loop.run_until_complete(). asyncio.run() управляет жизненным циклом событий, включая создание и закрытие цикла, что делает код проще.
app.run_polling() уже является асинхронным методом, и он сам управляет запуском цикла событий, поэтому нет необходимости вручную контролировать цикл.
